# How can I make this in one line?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

How can I make this one line?

```
<div data-reactroot="">
    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="/home">Home</a>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="/about">About</a>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="/services">Services</a>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="/contact-us">Contact us</a>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you putting links to the Stackoverflow site and asking how can you put them in one line ?

Comment: He just didn't properly format his code so it appeared that way, I've edited it to look normal now.

Answer (score 0):

This should put everything into one line:

```
<div data-reactroot="">
    <a href="/home">Home</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
    <a href="/services">Services</a>
    <a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="/contact-us">Contact us</a>
</div>
```

You just need to remove all the `<br>` tags (which are used for breaking lines) and keep them in the same `<div>` to override any styles that may be placing them on new line.

Answer (score 0):

You used 4 tags that are completely unrelated with the problem. You want do display those links side by side? That's a CSS related issue.